# jquery remove list item where .text() = 'blabla'

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure

```
<ul>
 <li><a ...>something</a></li>
 ...
 <li><a ...>blabla</a></li>
<ul>
```

I need to remove the `li` element where the text of the anchor is blabla.

How would i go about selecting this element?
`$(--what selector here--)`

or do I need to loop over each `li` and compare its `.text()` value to 'blabla'?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want a *contains* (substring match) then [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) works:

```
$('li:contains("blabla")').remove();
```

If you want an *exact* match, e.g. not matching "blablabla", you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('li').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === 'blabla'; }).remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li > a:contains("blabla")').remove();
```

Have a look at the [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

I've [just noticed](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj5yJ/) that `:contains` does partial matching. You may need to do...

```
$('li > a:contains("blabla")').each(function() {
     if ($(this).text() === 'blabla') {
         $(this).parent().remove();
     }
});
```

You could also make the selector less strict if doing it that way.

... or you could do it [much neater like Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713664/jquery-remove-list-item-where-text-blabla/3713677#3713677).

Comment: These won't remove the `<li>`. They will remove the `<a>` instead.

Comment: Since the `<a>` is the only content of the `<li>` you can just do the check on the `<li>` element's text :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid removing `li`s containing `blabla` unless `blabla` is further nested, use this:

`$("ul li > a:contains('blabla')").parent().remove()`;

Otherwise, the first `li` from this HTML will be removed even though "blabla" is not where you might be targeting it:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            Some nested content here:
            <span>
                Blablabla
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This one also is targeting the `<a>` instead of the `<li>`.