# Remove div containing specific text and elements

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="block">
    text
</div>
<div class="block">
    text
</div>
<div class="block">
    text <button />
</div>
```

Using jQuery, how can I remove the div containing both text and a button. I don't want to use `:last`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery remove list item where .text() = 'blabla'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713664/jquery-remove-list-item-where-text-blabla)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
$(".block:contains(text)").filter(function () {
    return $(this).children("button").length > 0;
}).remove();
```

First look for elements with class `block` that contain `"text"`, and then filter out the one that has a button as child. There might be a better way of doing it.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6fUfk/

Answer (score 11):

```
$("div:contains('text')").remove()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. This is the correct answer. The other answer did not work for me.