# Jquery remove li with certain text

Tags: jquery

I would like to do this using Jquery
situation:

```
<li>text:</li>
<li>:</li>
```

I want to remove the li that contains ":" and only ":"
Outcome:

```
<li>text:</li>
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713664/jquery-remove-list-item-where-text-blabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this .

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){
  $( 'li' ).each( function(){
    var text = $( this ).text();
    if ( text === ':' ) {
      $( this ).remove();
    }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>text:</li>
<li>:</li>
```

Comment: How does this append the colon to previous node?

Comment: Is it the same if the li is inside a div? so I just change it from $('li').each to $('div li').each

Comment: I don't understand. 
Why does it have to append a colon to the previous node ?

Comment: @Rohit I think it's the ===

Comment: @CianFlint it would work for all li as of now, but I really suggest if you can, then give this li some sort of class, else it would iterate over all the <li> elements in the document, which can be a lot of iterations.

Comment: @ankur - see the expected output of OP

Comment: @Rohit I don't see an extra colon. 
Both the nodes have colons in the end

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I thought the first node didn't have a colon at the end. And then its a duplicate of this question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713664/jquery-remove-list-item-where-text-blabla