# Hide list items based on their value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript or Jquery I need to hide any elements in a list with the value '0'.

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/, https://api.jquery.com/hide

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Sourav answer (using :contains) is that it will also match anything else that 'contains' a 0. E.g. 10, 20 etc

Try this instead:

**This actually removes the element from the DOM:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === '0';
      })
      .remove()
    })
  </script>
```

**This element will remain in the DOM, but will not be visible:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === '0';
      })
      .hide()
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: `$(this).text()` would be more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for this, this works well, however the problem with this solution is that it only works if the list items containt only '0'. 
What if the list item contains '<li>This is number 0</li>' etc.?

Comment: Thanks Rory, your right. I'll amend the examples :)

Comment: Ruben, could you update your question and clearly explain what your use case is? The example you provided (for which we all gave answers for) doesn't contain any other text. You simply asked to remove the item if the value is 0

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this. One line solution when you don't want to match it exact.

```js
$('li:contains(0)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

OR if you want to remove li with only 0 then you can do it like below.

```js
$('li').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === '0'; }).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713677/10971575

Comment: This will also remove any other numbers that 'contain' a 0. E.g. 10, 20 etc

Comment: See my updated answer. For both cases.

Comment: Did you just copy my answer?

Comment: Nope. Just read the documentation for jquery and got from it.

Comment: This isn't an example from the documentation, although is identical to my example?

Comment: Got from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713677/10971575

Answer (score 1):

try this code sample it remove the li with 0 value

```js
$('#list li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === '0';
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
       <li>0</li>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>0</li>
       <li>3</li>
       <li>4</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
 if($( this ).text() == 0){
  $( this ).hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's gone mad for jQuery in their answers, but the vanilla JS is just as short, and you don't need the overhead of loading jQuery in.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')]
  .filter(el => el.textContent === '0')
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add('hidden'));
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```